# try and catch java

Tags: java, user-interface, try-catch

I have been making a GUI program and I am calling a method that throws an exception. I have to use a try and catch because i cannot edit the code because its GUI. For some reason the code just doesnt work. The code is supposed to get the first line of a file and display the number in a label. Here is the code:

```
    try{  
       String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter The File Name: ");
       int x= codeReadFile(inputStr);
       String name= String.valueOf(x);
       chipCount.setText(name);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No File");

    }
```

the code for the filereading program is:

```
      public static int codeReadFile (String filename) throws IOException, 
      FileNotFoundException {
      String line=null;
      int value=0;
      BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new 
            InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename)));
            while (( line = inputReader.readLine()) != null)
                value = Integer.parseInt(line);
                inputReader.close();
                return value;
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What exactly are you encountering?

Comment: I have nothing show up when i run it. I am pretty sure that its the try and catch statements because when i just write chipCount.setText(10) for example it does work and display it.

Comment: It smells like your `codeReadFile(String)` is broken. Please add its code.

Comment: the code for codeReadFile() is  public static int codeReadFile (String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        String line=null;
        int value=0;
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new 
                InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename)));
                while (( line = inputReader.readLine()) != null)
                    value = Integer.parseInt(line);
                    inputReader.close();
                    return value;

Comment: Obviously, you must catch **all** exceptions, and not just `IOException` if you want to ensure that something is shown in the GUI. Please, **don't post code in comments**. Edit the question.

Comment: Your codeReadFile does not return the first value in the file, but the last one... Could that be part of your problem?

Comment: Add the line `System.out.println(new File(fileName)).getAbsolutePath());` at the first statement in `codeReadFile()` Does it show the file you are expecting? If yes, also try `System.out.println(line);` right before your `return value` statement. Is it what you expected?

Comment: I only have one value in the file. There will never be more than one.

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to get the first line of the file, but this code obviously doesn't do that:

```
while (( line = inputReader.readLine()) != null)
  value = Integer.parseInt(line);
```

It tries to read the whole file and parse every line as an `int`, discarding all values but the last. What you probably wanted to say is

```
line = inputReader.readLine();
return line != null? Integer.parseInt(line) : 0;
```

You should have such code **whether or not your file actually contains only one line**. For example, if the file contains an extra line break, you'll read an empty line, try to parse it, and get a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: okay thanks, I fixed it but i still am not getting any results

Answer (score 0):

GUI Operations should always be invoked on the EDT(Event Dispatch Thread). You can reach that by wrapping the modifying code into sth. like:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chipCount.setText(name);
            }
        });
```

Otherwise ugly things may happen ;)

Then there's also an easier way to retrieve an `BufferedReader`. Simply drop the streams and use a `FileReader` instead.

The last thing is: If your file only contains one line, just read one.
What you're doing is reading all lines. If the last one is empty, you're getting a wrong result or even a NumberFormatException by `parseInt()`.

As another approach you could try to call `repaint()` or `invalidate()` on chipCount and/or its parent after you set the text. 
**Edit:**
I just read you want to display that in a label... then repaint is definitively the way to go. You could also just use a `JTextField` and make it uneditable to get rid of this.